# Link tracking with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am mailing a newsletter which has some links to my website. I need to keep count of these link clicks. How can i keep track of this using google analytics.

I am new to google analytics. i tried this link builder
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578
http://www.xyz.com/?utm_source=src&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=support

but these parameters are not appearing in traffic sources of dashboard.

please help.

Comment: Are you only tracking total click totals or do you need per email or unique only clicks?

Comment: only click totals

Answer (score 3):

They appear under campaigns, which is under traffic sources. In your example URL the campaign would be `support`.

Comment: I just made some clicks on my URL. it seems like dashboard doesnt show todays visitor count. will it be updated one day later or does this happen right away.

Comment: It takes a day or so.